# Better "Split-ArrayInChunks" for PowerShell

Tags: arrays, performance, powershell, arraylist

When using an script that based on arrays for my "Split-ArrayInChunks" method takes it ages to process 190.000+ records, my initial version based on this code (see [Split up an array into chunks and start a job on each one.](https://mjolinor.wordpress.com/2011/01/30/split-up-an-array-into-chunks-and-start-a-job-on-each-one/))

```
$computers = gc c:\somedir\complist.txt
$n = 6
$complists = @{}
$count = 0 
$computers |% {$complists[$count % $n] += @($_);$count++}

0..($n-1) |% {
start-job -scriptblock {gwmi win32_operatingsystem -computername $args} -argumentlist $complists[$_]
}
```

I found this article [Performance: The += Operator (and When to Avoid It)](http://powershell.org/wp/2013/09/16/powershell-performance-the-operator-and-when-to-avoid-it/) and basically recommends the author to use "System.Collections.Generic.List" or "System.Collections.ArrayList" instead of arrays. So I came up with this implementation:

```
function Split-ArrayInChunks_UsingGenericList($inArray, $numberOfChunks) {

    $list = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[System.Collections.Generic.List[PSCustomObject]]
    $count = 0 

    # populate with empty lists
    0..($numberOfChunks-1) | % {
        $list.Add((New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[PSCustomObject]))
    }

    # create packages
    $inArray | % { 
        $list[$count % $numberOfChunks].Add($_); 
        $count++ 
    }

    return $list.ToArray()
}
```

I also tried to use "System.Collections.ArrayList", but this function returns an flat array. Inside the function is $arrayList an nested array, but once outside the function do I have an flat array (192169 items instead of 10 chunks).

```
function Split-ArrayInChunks_UsingArrayList($inArray, $numberOfChunks) {

    $arryList = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
    $count = 0 

    # populate 
    0..($numberOfChunks-1) | % {
        $arryList.Add((New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList))
    }

    $inArray | % { 
        $arryList[$count % $numberOfChunks].Add($_); 
        $count++ 
    }

    Write-Host 'Number of arryList:'$arryList.Count
    Write-Host 'Number of items in first arryList:' $arryList[0].Count
    return $arryList
}
```

To illustrate the "flat" problem generates the following code...

```
Write-Host '-------------------------------'
$packages1 = Split-ArrayInChunks_UsingGenericList $data.CrmRecords 10
Write-Host 'Number of packages1:'$packages1.Count
Write-Host 'Number of items in first package1:' $packages1[0].Count

Write-Host '-------------------------------'
$packages2 = Split-ArrayInChunks_UsingArrayList $data.CrmRecords 10
Write-Host 'Number of packages2:'$packages2.Count
Write-Host 'Number of items in first package2:' $packages2[0].Count
```

...this output:

```
-------------------------------
Number of packages1: 10
Number of items in first package1: 19215
-------------------------------
Number of arryList: 10
Number of items in first arryList: 19215
Number of packages2: 192169
Number of items in first package2: 1
```

So I have two questions:

1. Any option to improve improve my "Split-ArrayInChunks_UsingArrayList" version (e.g. faster, more readable)?
2. Why is the return value of "ArrayInChunks_UsingArrayList" an flat array,  inside the function is %arrayList an nested array?

**Update 2016-02-04:** I updated my code based on the feedback (use [void] to prevent the polluting of the output) and it works. The only strang thing is the fact that when I use |format-table is my version (Split-ArrayInChunks_UsingArrayList) again printed as flat list:

```
function Split-ArrayInChunks_UsingArrayList($inArray, $numberOfChunks) {
    $arryList = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
    $count = 0 

    # populate 
    0..($numberOfChunks-1) | % {

        [void]$arryList.Add((New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList))
    }

    $inArray | % { 
        [void]$arryList[$count % $numberOfChunks].Add($_); 
        $count++ 
    }

    return $arryList
}

function Split-ArrayInChunks_CommunityVersion($inArray, $numberOfChunks) {
    $Lists = @{}
    $count = 0 

    # populate 
    0..($numberOfChunks-1) | % {
        $Lists[$_] = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
    }

    $inArray | % { 
        [void]$Lists[$count % $numberOfChunks].Add($_); 
        $count++ 
    }

    return $Lists
}
```

When I execute this code...

```
Write-Host 'CommunityVersion'
Write-Host '-------------------------------'
Split-ArrayInChunks_CommunityVersion $list 6 | Format-Table -AutoSize

Write-Host 'ArrayInChunks_UsingArrayList'
Write-Host '-------------------------------'
Split-ArrayInChunks_UsingArrayList $list 6 | Format-Table -AutoSize
```

... is this the output in the console:

```
CommunityVersion
-------------------------------

Name Value                                 
---- -----                                 
5    {denn, getan, verhaftet}              
4    {haben, Böses, Morgens, war}          
3    {verleumdet, etwas, eines, es}        
2    {Josef K., er, er, er}                
1    {musste, dass, wurde, sagte}          
0    {Jemand, ohne, hätte, »Wie ein Hund!«}


ArrayInChunks_UsingArrayList
-------------------------------
Jemand
ohne
hätte
»Wie ein Hund!«
musste
dass
wurde
sagte
Josef K.
er
er
er
verleumdet
etwas
eines
es
haben
Böses
Morgens
war
denn
getan
verhaftet
```

I do not understand why "ArrayInChunks_UsingArrayList" is printed as list, it is an nested array, just like "ArrayInChunks_CommunityVersion".

Comment: `ArrayList.Add` is not `void`.

Comment: If you're reading a list from a file, why not just use -ReadCount ?

Comment: @mjolinor: Not sure what you mean. In my case i load these 190.000+ records form an web-service. I need to package these record into chunks, so that I can process the chunks in jobs.

Comment: Left a proposed answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, here's how I'd do that:

```
function Split-ArrayInChunks_UsingArrayList($inArray, $numberOfChunks) {

    $Lists = @{}
    $count = 0 

    # populate 
    0..($numberOfChunks-1) | % {
        $Lists[$_] = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
    }

    $inArray | % { 
        [void]$Lists[$count % $numberOfChunks].Add($_); 
        $count++ 
    }

    Write-Host 'Number of arryList:'$Lists.Count
    Write-Host 'Number of items in first arryList:' $Lists[0].Count
    return $Lists
}
```

Comment: Real issue observed in the question is that OP pollutes his output with the return value from (`ArrayList.Add()`) - you need to supress those calls

Comment: @Mathias Ah.  Fixed. Thanks.

Comment: @mjolinor I updated my question see "Update 2016-02-04". Your version works as expected, but "ArrayList in ArrayList" approach prints again ain flat list. Any idea why this is?

Comment: @thuld That is because PowerShell formatter work this way. `Get-Help Format-Table -Parameter Expand`. `Split-ArrayInChunks_UsingArrayList $list 6 | Format-Table -AutoSize -Expand CoreOnly`.

Comment: @PetSerAl Ok, but both functions return an array of "System.Collections.ArrayList" items. I would assume that "| format table" yields the same result!?

Comment: @thuld `Split-ArrayInChunks_UsingArrayList` return multiple `ArrayList`s, but `Split-ArrayInChunks_CommunityVersion` return single `Hashtable`. `Split-ArrayInChunks_UsingArrayList $list 6|%{"Item from pipeline: $($_.GetType().FullName)."}`. `Split-ArrayInChunks_CommunityVersion $list 6|%{"Item from pipeline: $($_.GetType().FullName)."}`.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the usage of "$inArray | % " makes the operation so slow. When using a normal foreach loop takes it less then 2 second to create the chunks. When using the "$inArray | % " based version it takes **20 seconds**:

```
function Split-ArrayInChunks_Fast($inArray, $numberOfChunks) {

    $arrayList = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
    $count = 0 

    # populate 
    0..($numberOfChunks-1) | % {
        [void]$arrayList.Add((New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList))
    }

    foreach($elem in $inArray) {

       [void]$arrayList[$count % $numberOfChunks].Add($elem) 
       $count++ 
    }

    return $arrayList.ToArray()
}

function Split-ArrayInChunks_Slow($inArray, $numberOfChunks) {

    $arrayList = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
    $count = 0 

    # populate 
    0..($numberOfChunks-1) | % {
        [void]$arrayList.Add((New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList))
    }

    $inArray | % { 
        [void]$arrayList[$count % $numberOfChunks].Add($_); 
        $count++ 
    }

    return $arrayList.ToArray()
}
```